# Putting add in android app

Tags: android, admob

I want to put a small banner advertisement in my android app. I tried using ad-mob, but i did not get it. Do i need to pay to put adds in my application. Can any body suggest me how to put it. First i want to do it test it and then publish. I tried using the guide form the developers.google.com , I did not get it

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

// Create the adView
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, MY_AD_UNIT_ID);

// Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it's been given
// the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

// Add the adView to it
layout.addView(adView);

// Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Do i need to pay to put adds in my application`

No you do not need to pay anything. You should have ad-mob account to use ad-id.

Make sure you declared internet permission in manifest.xml and added .jar file to build-path.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Should i remove the following line from xml file while launching the app in playstore. ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR,8D6A60795107D66881239CA9865CA4D5"

Comment: I got publisher id like this -> Publisher ID: pub-7591964711364574 .But the publisher id must be 15 character alphanumeric. Can u help me ?